# Return an object variable from a script - Azure YAML pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Consider the following simplified pipeline:

```
### template.yml ###
parameters:
  - name: "tables"
    type: object
    default: {}
 
steps:
  - ${{ each table in parameters.tables }}:
      - task: BackupTask@0
        displayName: "Backup ${{ table }}"
```

```
### pipeline.yml ###
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    tables:
      - "table1"
      - "table2"
      - "table3"
      - "table4"
      - "table5"
```

What I would like is that the list of tables are generated with a bash script instead of having to write them by hand. So every time a new table is created it gets automatically backed up by the pipeline.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I'm afraid the workaround if too complicated for what I need. I was hoping to see other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can create another pipeline. In this pipeline, we add two powershell tasks. In the first task, we set a variable with tables as the value.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: 'Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=list]table1,table2,table3"'
```

In the second task, we use [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to trigger the `pipeline.yml` pipeline. In the request body, we use the variable set in the first task as the value of the template parameter.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "PAT"
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = @'
      {
        "templateParameters": {
          "tab":"[$(list)]"
         },
      }
      '@
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

Below is my test sample:

```
### pipeline.yml ###
parameters:
  - name: tab
    type: object
    default: {}

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:  
- template: template1.yml
  parameters:
    tables: ${{ parameters.tab }}
```

template.yml:

```
### template1.yml ###
parameters:
  - name: "tables"
    type: object
    default: {}
 
steps:
   - ${{ each table in parameters.tables }}:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: echo "${{ table }}"
```

Then we run the newly created pipeline to trigger the `pipeline.yml` pipeline, get the result:

[image]